# JPanel Graphics clearing and repainting?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paintcomponent

I have a `JPanel` with a `paintComponent()` function. I'll call it once, then when the user clicks a different `JButton`, I'll set some flag and want to call this function again as it will do something slightly different after the flag is set.

So here's what I'm wondering: how do I clear the existing stuff from `paintComponent`? And to redraw, do I just call `paintComponent` again?

Currently I'm trying the following:

```
flag2 = true;
repaint(); //I expect (want) paintComponent to be called again
```

In paint component, I do stuff like:

```
if (flag2==true) {
    g.drawRect(...);
} else {
    g.drawLine(...);
}
```

But through testing it seems like there is something wrong with what I'm doing.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You're not calling repaint() from within the paintComponent method, are you?  Are you sure the repaint() call is associated with the panel you want refreshed? (e.g. myPanel.repaint())?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you change a property of the panel then you need to invoke:

```
panel.repaint();
```

to cause the component to be repainted.

Then the first statement in the paintComponent() method should be:

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

This will paint the background so you can now do your custom painting.

If you need more help then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 14):

To clear all previously drawn graphics, invoke [`g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight())`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#clearRect-int-int-int-int-).

Answer (score 2):

First, why not use an enum instead of a boolean?

```
enum Enum { 
    RECTANGLE,
    LINE,
    CIRCLE
}

Enum choice = RECTANGLE; //default to RECTANGLE

switch(choice) { 
   // case RECTANGLE, LINE, CIRCLE
}
```

With regards to your issue, can you answer my comments in your question?

Comment: The logic I have is fine, I could probably use enum but whatever that's not my problem. My problem is that I need to clear all drawn graphics and then call paintComponent again somehow for this JPanel.

Comment: You shouldn't need to clear all the graphics to achieve what you want.

Comment: See camickr's answer, if you aren't doing what he's outlined, focus on that first.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest calling revalidate(); instead of repaint(). revalidate() needs to be called when changing the size / layout or when you add/remove objects onto your jpanel and will update all of it's children. From what I can tell, you're still using the same paint object tho but changing it's layout.